# React - Log Out UseContext

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I would like to create a log out with useContext - ReactJS. For this, I would like to empty my useContext.

This is my `App.jsx`:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import HeaderAuth from "./components/templates/header-auth";
import Header from "./components/templates/header";
import Login from "./components/authentification/login";
import Register from "./components/authentification/register";
import Password from "./components/authentification/password";
import HomePage from "./components//homePage";
import Profile from "./components/authentification/profile";
import Footer from "./components/templates/footer";
import "./app.scss";

// CONTEXTS
import User from "./contexts/userContext";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <main id="App" className="App">
      <ToastContainer position="top-left" autoClose={5000} />
      <User.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
        <Router>
          {user ? <Header /> : <HeaderAuth />}
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
            <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register />} />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/login/identity/forgotten-password"
              element={<Password />}
            />
            <Route exact path="/hp" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </Router>
      </User.Provider>
    </main>
  );
}
```

And this is what I tried to code -> my dropdown where I put the log out button:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext } from "react";

// CONTEXT
import User from "../../../contexts/userContext";

export default function Menu() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useContext(User);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogOut = () => {
    setCurrentUser({});
    navigate("/");
  };

  console.log(currentUser);

  return (
    <ul className="menuProfile">
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/profile">Mon profil</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleLogOut}>
          Déconnexion
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

I don't know why, but I get this error:

[image: Error]

Do you have any idea why I get this error?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: Where is `<Menu>` relative to `<User.Provider>`? And what is the default value of the context?

Comment: Can you provide the `userContext` file ?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:
`const [ currentUser, setCurrentUser ] = useContext(User);`

To this one:
`const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = useContext(User);`

You are getting that error because you are trying to destructure the context value as an array, but it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

You destructure the ctx as an array.

Replace the first line of your Menu component with the following

```
const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = useContext(User);
```